# Stuck with sql subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have these 3 tables :

```
1) Sailors (sid:INT, sname:VARCHAR(30), rating:INT, age:INT)
2) Boats (bid:INT, bname:VARCHAR(30), color:VARCHAR(10))
3) Reserves (bid:INT, sid:INT, day:DATE)
```

I want to write a query which displays the number(bid) of every boat that has been reserved by all the sailors at least once/
So far I wrote this :

```
SELECT b.bid, b.bname
FROM boats as b , sailors as s , reserves as r
WHERE r.bid = b.bid and r.sid = s.sid
GROUP BY r.bid
HAVING count(r.sid) = count(s.sid)
```

It seems the right answer to me but after trying it on MYSQL id didn't work.

Comment: Do the tables relate to one another in some way? And who upvotes this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried comparing the count of boat reserves to count of sailors like this?

```
HAVING count(r.sid) = (Select count(sid) from sailors)
```

you also need to make sure that count(r.sid) is a unique count of bid and sid incase the same sailor reserved the same boat more than once.

```
SELECT  g.bid, 
        g.name
FROM    
    (SELECT b.bid, b.name, s.sid
        FROM boats AS b, reserves AS r, sailors AS s
        WHERE   b.bid = r.bid AND r.sid = s.sid
        GROUP BY b.bid, b.name, s.sid
    ) AS g
GROUP BY g.bid, g.name
HAVING  COUNT(g.bid) = (SELECT COUNT(s.SID) FROM sailors AS s)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several query patterns that will return the specified result.

Assuming that the `sid` column in the `Reserves` table is a FOREIGN KEY referencing `Sailors(sid)`, we can use a distinct count of `sid` from the `Reserves` table for a given boat, and compare that to a distinct count of `sid` from `Sailors`.

For example:

```
   SELECT b.bid
        , b.bname
     FROM Boats b
     JOIN ( SELECT rr.bid
                 , COUNT(DISTINCT rr.sid) AS cnt
              FROM Reserves rr
             GROUP BY rr.bid
          ) r
       ON r.bid = b.bid
     JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ss.sid) AS cnt
              FROM Sailors ss
          ) s
       ON s.cnt = r.cnt
```

The inline view aliased as `r` gets us a count of distinct `sid` values for each boat, from the `Reserves` table.

The inline view aliased as `s` gets us a count of distinct `sid` values from `Sailors`.  If `sid` is the PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY of `Sailors` (which is what we expect, it's the normative pattern) we can omit the `DISTINCT` keyword. The question did not indicate if this was the case, so rather than making a wrong assumption, we write a query that will work in the more general case.)

This query did assume that there was a foreign key constraint... that rows in `Reserves` would not have a non-NULL value that didn't reference a row in `Sailors`.  If that's not the case, we can modify the inline view query `r`, so we get a distinct count of `sid` values that appear in the `Sailors` table.

This can replace the inline view query `r` above:

```
          ( SELECT rr.bid
                 , COUNT(DISTINCT rr.sid) AS cnt
              FROM Reserves rr
              JOIN Sailors rs 
                ON rs.sid = rr.sid
             GROUP BY rr.bid
          ) r
```

This query pattern can easily be adapted to check conditions other than *ALL* sailors.

And there are other query patterns that can achieve an equivalent result.

Comment: Anyone care to explain a reason that this answer deserves the  downvote?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Check This out :)

```
===============================================
CREATE TABLE Sailors (sid INT, sname VARCHAR(30), rating INT, age INT)
INSERT INTO Sailors values (1,'S1',100,20);
INSERT INTO Sailors values (2,'S2',100,20);
INSERT INTO Sailors values (3,'S3',100,20);
INSERT INTO Sailors values (4,'S4',100,20);
INSERT INTO Sailors values (5,'S5',100,20);

CREATE TABLE Boats (bid INT, bname VARCHAR(30), color VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO Boats values (1,'B1','Blue');
INSERT INTO Boats values (2,'B2','Red');
INSERT INTO Boats values (3,'B3','Green');
INSERT INTO Boats values (4,'B4','Blue');
INSERT INTO Boats values (5,'B5','Green');

CREATE TABLE Reserves (bid INT, sid INT, day DATE)
INSERT INTO Reserves values (1,1,'2015-01-01');
INSERT INTO Reserves values (1,2,'2015-01-01');
INSERT INTO Reserves values (1,3,'2015-01-01');
INSERT INTO Reserves values (1,4,'2015-01-01');
INSERT INTO Reserves values (1,5,'2015-01-01');
INSERT INTO Reserves values (2,1,'2015-01-01');
INSERT INTO Reserves values (2,2,'2015-01-01');
INSERT INTO Reserves values (2,3,'2015-01-01');
INSERT INTO Reserves values (2,4,'2015-01-01');
INSERT INTO Reserves values (2,5,'2015-01-01');
INSERT INTO Reserves values (2,3,'2015-01-02');
INSERT INTO Reserves values (2,4,'2015-01-03');
INSERT INTO Reserves values (2,5,'2015-01-04');
INSERT INTO Reserves values (3,1,'2015-01-02');
INSERT INTO Reserves values (4,1,'2015-01-03');
INSERT INTO Reserves values (5,1,'2015-01-04');
===============================================

SELECT Reserves.bid , Boats.bname  FROM Reserves , Boats 
WHERE Reserves.bid  = Boats.bid
GROUP BY Reserves.bid , Boats.bname
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT  Reserves.sid) = (SELECT COUNT(sid) FROM Sailors)

Result ===>
BID       BNAME
---------------
1         B1 
2         B2
```

Hope it will help :)